# USB devices disconnect while using (LTS 20.04)

Tags: boot, 20.04, usb

I am having trouble with the USB ports (LTS 20.04) .
The problem:
All usb connected devices will become undetected while using, but the HDMI cable on the same type-c hub is still working.[The hub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuGNh.jpg)

However, reboot will fix this problem for a while.

I searched some QAs, and I change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

in /etc/default/grub into

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1".
```

But It doesn't help.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  After you made the change to the `/etc/default/grub` file did you run `sudo update-grub` and reboot?  I can't assume that you did since you didn't write it into your question. Also, any more details about your troubleshooting as well as your hardware like motherboard model etc can really help us help you.

Comment: Hi, I did run sudo update-grub. The problem is actully solved by reinstalling ubuntu. Thank you.